# Dynamic Images are not shown in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm trying to show images dynamically in `tcpdf`. This image path is absolute and its comes from another server. But when `pdf` is generated, its not show images. If I give local path, then its working. I'm using latest version of `TCPDF`.

Is there any need to change the tcpdf 's configuration ???

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure tcpdf support absolute path or not , but when i was working on tcpdf i also face the same problem so what i did , first i download all the related required images to our server using the following function ->

```
function copyImages($filepath, $fileLocalServerPath) {
    if (!copy($file, $fileLocalServerPath)) {
        echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
    }
 }
```

After this i used the relative path bz now all the images are on our server.

Comment: :thanks for reply.your server path is http or https? http file path are supported.Could you please write the whole code?